# Area of a subregion of a trapezium determined by a diagonal and an auxiliary line

Tags: geometry

[image]

ED=15, AC=24 and the height of the trapezium is 12. If point B splits AC in half, the area of quadrilateral OBCD is what?

This question was part of an exam I recieved. Can someone help me. I can't answer it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what concept specifically you are finding difficult and show at least some form of attempt at a solution. :)

Comment: What is the area of triangle ABE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of $OBCD$ is area of $ADC$ (which is $144$) minus that
of $OAB$. The area of $OAB$ is $6h$ where $h$ is the height of
$O$ above $AB$.

The triangles $OAB$ and $ODE$ are similar. As $|AB|=\frac45|DE|$
then $h=\frac45(12-h)$ giving $9 h=48$, that is $h=\frac{16}3$.
So $OAB$ has area $32$ and the area you seek is $112$.